# How does the 'in' operator determine membership?

Tags: python

How does the `in` operator work for Python?

In the example below I have two namedtuples that are different objects, but the `in` operator evaluates to True for an array containing one of the objects.

Is `in` checking if the array contains the object, or does it check if any object in the array is equivalent? I tried searching for documentation but couldn't find anything specific, just simple examples.

```
In [3]: a = namedtuple('test', ['t'])                             

In [6]: b = a(1)                      

In [7]: c = a(1)                      

In [8]: b is c                        
Out[8]: False                         

In [9]: id(b)                         
Out[9]: 54740808                      

In [10]: id(c)                        
Out[10]: 88817352                     

In [11]: c in [b]                     
Out[11]: True                         

In [12]: b in [c]                     
Out[12]: True                         

In [13]: c == b                       
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: what `in` does is defined by the `__contains__()` method of the object on the right side of the operator. in case if that is a `list` it calls the `__eq__()` method (this can be uncovered by implementing a class with a custom `__eq__()` method), at `set` or `dict_keys` it compares the hash I guess, but not sure. also if any element does not have an `__eq__()` method `in` does not return `NotImplemented` those are just skipped silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator is checking  the array contains the object which value is equivalent.
Here is example:

```
In [1]: a = {}

In [2]: b = {}

In [3]: c = [a]

In [4]: id(a), id(b), id(c[0])
Out[4]: (4514911128, 4515638640, 4514911128)

In [5]: a in c
Out[5]: True

In [6]: b in c
Out[6]: True
```